# openam authentication for only one website

Tags: openam

I have more than 10 websites on my server but I need OpenAM for only one of them. I tried installing OpenAM but it goes for all of them.

My websites are hosted on CPanel and WHM.

Answer (score 0):

you may look at not-enforced-list invert feature of the agent and only add the URLs for the site you wanted to be protected